# Emploi pragmatique et/ou intensif de l'adverbe « toujours » : position dans la phrase, nuances ?

Tags: oral, adverbes, syntaxe, linguistique

Il existe certaines valeurs ou fonctions plus abstraites que celles ayant trait au temps que peut prendre l'adverbe [*toujours*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toujours). [*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/toujours/78644?q=toujours#77718) y fait allusion de deux manières, avec l'idée de la « possibilité souvent très incertaine dans l'avenir (surtout après pouvoir ou après un impératif) : *Viens toujours, on verra bien.* » mais surtout avec celle de l'*intensif* comme dans « *c'est toujours mieux que rien*. » (Larousse). Au *DHLF/Rey* on parle de valeur "dite « de circonstance logique »" qu'on atteste en 1520, provenant d'une « correspondance temporelle entre deux choses d'abord après un verbe. » avec valeur du type *en tout cas, quoiqu'il arrive* (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, dir. A. Rey, ed. Le Robert, *jour/toujours*). Valeur qu'on rend par *en tout cas, en attendant* au *LBU* (§ 1006 e 3), où l'on a par ailleurs des exemples, qu'on dit retrouver souvent dans des dialogues, et où parfois l'adverbe *toujours* apparaît en fin de phrase, postposé :

> (1) Je vais toujours commencer ma lettre [...], sans savoir quand j'aurai le
> temps de la finir. (Châteaubriand)
>  (2) Descendez toujours ; je prends
> mon manteau et je vous rejoins. (Gide)
>  (3) J'ai eu bien peur,
> toujours ! (Musset)
>  (4) Que cela ne t'arrive plus, toujours !
> (Hugo)
>  (5) Tu n'es pas allé chez moi, toujours ? (Genevoix)
>
> ---
>
> À ça j'ajouterais :
>  (6) J'vas toujours ben m'en prendre quequ'paquets
> pendant qu'y me voient pas ! (Tremblay)

Le *TLFi* a une section fort intéressante sur les emplois qu'il dit *pragmatiques*, dont ceux-ci :

> [Marque la prise en charge d'une conclusion jugée acquise en tout état
> de cause, ne serait-ce que par le fait qu'elle engage fort peu] Rem.
> La conclusion en cause ,,ne soulève pas elle-même d'objection
> sérieuse; elle ne coûte rien, ou bien, si elle consiste en une action,
> cette action ne comporte pas de risque important ou encore est
> réversible, annulable`` (Modèles ling. t. 7, 2 1985, p. 117). *Dites toujours. Passons toujours prendre le café au salon* (A. Daudet, *Tartarin Alpes*, 1885, p. 225). *− Faut pourtant que je l'achète, le petit café (...) − Achetez-le toujours. Si ce n'est pas moi... ce sera une autre* (Mirbeau, *Journal femme ch.*, 1900, p. 215).
>
> [Marque la prise en charge d'un argument, sans doute faible, mais
> considéré comme acquis et qui restera valable quoi qu'il arrive] Rem.
> Dans ce sens, toujours ,,introduit dans un argument, indique pourquoi
> il faut prendre en considération cet argument, en mettant en œuvre le
> principe: « si faible que soit un argument, il reste un argument et il
> faut le suivre si on n'a pas d'argument plus fort en sens inverse »``
> (Modèles ling. t. 7, 2 1985, p. 122). La valeur est proche de *en tout
> cas, de toute façon, quoi qu'il en soit: Angélique donna son aumône. −
> Voilà toujours un pain. − Oh! du pain, reprit la mère* (Zola, *Rêve*,
> 1888, p. 84).
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé*, TLFi, extraits des
> remarques à II. B. et C., [*toujours*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toujours) ]

---

Sempiternel duo de questions :

- La position du *toujours* (pragmatique, de circonstance logique, intensif etc. mais non pas temporel) dans les exemples relève-t-elle ici davantage du besoin d'éviter de reproduire certaines constructions usuelles que d'un ordre particulier (C'est-à-dire, par exemple, qu'avec le premier exemple, placer *toujours* après *lettre* donne *toujours sans*, où le pragmatisme est complètement éteint.) ? Doit-on nuancer entre le sens pragmatique et le sens intensif de *toujours* dans ce contexte ?
- Avec ce genre d'emploi, l'adverbe peut-il apparaître en amont dans la phrase uniquement avec un infinitif (1) ou est-ce du à la présence d'un verbe particulier, comme *aller* (1)(5)(6) ; pouvait-on ne pas postposer l'adverbe dans les phrases (3) (4) et (5) ; qu'est-ce qui fait que ça fonctionne, que ça reste cohérent, ou non ?

Answer (score 1):

Tout d'abord, il n'y a pas vraiment de nuance entre ce que certains dictionnaires appellent le sens "pragmatique" et d'autres le sens "intensif", par opposition au sens "temporel" de l'adverbe toujours. Dans vos exemples, "toujours" apporte une idée de contrainte ou de rapport entre des choses.

Étymologiquement, il s'agit de l'emploi *explétif* de "toujours", où l'adverbe apporte une certaine couleur à la phrase, mais pourrait être tout à fait omis sans vraiment influencer la signification de la phrase.
Ce sont des cas où "toujours" pourrait être remplacé par "en tout cas".

Tous les exemples que vous citez sont donc "pragmatiques".

Les exemples (3) (4) et (5) sont néanmoins très inhabituels (aujourd'hui), à cause de la **position** de "toujours" en fin de phrase. L'usage de "toujours" en fin de phrase est vraiment très désuet. Sans contexte ou dialogue, il est quasi impossible pour le commun des mortels de comprendre ces trois phrases. Pour ces trois cas, on n'utilisera pas du tout "toujours". Donc en réalité, dans ces cas-ci, l'usage de "toujours" ne fonctionne *plus* aujourd'hui. On dira plutôt:

> (3) J'ai eu bien peur, **en tout cas** !
>   (4) Que cela ne t'arrive plus, **en tout cas** !

Le (5) est encore plus bizarre et vieillot. Encore dépendant du contexte, et on dirait aujourd'hui:

> (5) Tu n'es pas allé chez moi, **n'est-ce pas** ?

[Ce livre](https://books.google.com/books?id=UU_qfAk5MbAC&lpg=PA202&dq=%22Tu%20n'es%20pas%20all%C3%A9%20chez%20moi%2C%20toujours%20%3F%22&pg=PA202#v=onepage&q&f=false) parle explicitement de cet exemple en page 202.

Les autres exemples sont tout à fait compréhensibles tels quels et sans contexte, même le (6).

Pour ceux-là, "toujours" doit être situé juste après le verbe conjugué, avant le complément, et introduit alors une proposition subordonnée infinitive.
Donc, dire:

> Je vais commencer ma lettre **toujours,** sans savoir quand j'aurai le temps de la finir.

Ne fonctionnerait pas.

Comment: Merci, intéressant ! En fin de phrase suivant une tournure négative (4, 5), c'est présent à l'oral dans mon sociolecte, mais c'est possiblement le genre de truc que je régulariserais en m'adressant à qqn. dont je sais qu'il ne le partage pas. Peut-être que je choisirais le juron plutôt que _toujours_ en fin de phrase. Parfois ce n'est pas clair à savoir si c'est mon sociolecte ou moi uniquement.

Comment: Le 5) n'est pas si désuet... et on le remplacerait plutôt par "par hasard".

Comment: @ xenoid Vraiment ? Perso je ne dirais pas "toujours" en fin de phrase comme cela. Mais à tout à hasard, êtes vous québecois ou canadien ?